# ed25519 secret to public key

Tags: cryptography, ed25519

I am trying to use the python code given + test vector 2 given by rfc

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-7.1

[image]

## expected results

```
secret_to_public()

SecretKey = 4ccd089b28ff96da9db6c346ec114e0f

PublicKey = 3d4017c3e843895a92b70aa74d1b7ebc
```

## my result

```
    secret_to_public()

    SecretKey = 4ccd089b28ff96da9db6c346ec114e0f

    PublicKey = 4e15...56d7
```

## my concerns

1. Am I using the right secret key ?
   They seem to show a 64 byte secret key but ed25519 uses a 32 byte secret key.
2. Am I encoding the secret key / decoding the result correctly ?

## code

```
#https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-7.1

sK =    b"4ccd089b28ff96da9db6c346ec114e0f"

print(sK)
print(len(sK))

for i in range(32):
    print(hex(secret_to_public(sK)[i]))
```

Python Gist :
https://gist.github.com/redazul/668ca5d8501e73509a55777f5c84e469

Taken from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-6

Comment: Questions should be self contained, you should not have to go to some third-party site to find the code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've edited and added self contained code...but the person with the answer should be familiar with rfc-editor for context

Comment: The keys are hex encoded: `secret_to_public(bytes.fromhex('4ccd089b28ff96da9db6c346ec114e0f5b8a319f35aba624da8cf6ed4fb8a6fb')).hex()` returns the correct public key (also hex encoded).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Topaco

```
#https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-7.1
sK=bytes.fromhex("4ccd089b28ff96da9db6c346ec114e0f5b8a319f35aba624da8cf6ed4fb8a6fb")

print(sK)
print(len(sK))

for i in range(32):
    print(hex(secret_to_public(sK)[i]))
```